Replica of SaaS vendor replica DB
We have a SaaS vendor who will make data available via a replica Database(AWS RDS Postgres) only, we need to get this data(a replica of the replica). Looked into ETLs tools like Fivetran, Hevo but the limitation seems to lie with Postgres not allowing logical replication of a replica DB. Access to WAL might not be an option to explore. Looks like a typical scenario where a SaaS vendor would not expose anything other than a replica but the data integration solution does not seem simple though. What is the best way to replicate such a replica DB?
